# Is it possible to run flutter module on Web

Tags: flutter, dart

I have existing flutter module being used in native Android/iOS apps. After searching on internet I came to know that module cannot be used as it does not support web platform.

I am thinking about below approach

Creating new flutter app and copy existing module code (Not a good  solution as per me  because I will have to maintain 2 repos one for module(to support native platforms) and one for web app support).

**Queries:**

1. Has anyone come across such an issue and what are the possible ways to handle this scenario?
2. Can I embed this flutter app(not the flutter module) in native apps?Will this create any problem?

Please suggest possible solutions?